# How to find all occurrences of a regex between square brackets?

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word, office-interop

I'm opening a word doc using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`

```
word.Application wordApp = new word.Application { Visible = true };
word.Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: false, Visible: true);
aDoc.Activate();
```

What I want to do is find all text that is between `[]` for example `[Fruit]` or `[Pears]`

So this is a two part question

- How do you find all text in a word doc between []
- What is the appropriate regex for anything between square brackets []

Comment: No idea why the downvotes, so we a word example and i'll accept it

Comment: Try to use wildcard: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1501545/5045688).

Comment: If you plan to get a list/array of strings between `[` and `]` you just need to grab all text from the document and run  a well-known `\[([^][]*)]` regex on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try MatchCollection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "[Fruit] or [Pears]";
            string pattern = @"\[(?'fruit'[^\]]+)\]";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("fruit : '{0}'", match.Groups["fruit"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats the question, how do you do it in word

Comment: I like nawfal solution of getting all text in a word document.  Then applying my regex : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181085/how-to-get-text-from-line-number-in-ms-word

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "[first] second [third]";
var split = Regex.Matches(str, @"\[([A-Za-z])\w+\]");
List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in split)
{
      result.Add(match.Value.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']'));
}
```

Comment: How do you do it in word?